# Why doesn't my static block of code execute?

Tags: java, static

I am trying to run this code, I but found out this behavior of final with static: the code runs without executing static block of A. Please provide me with the reason.

```
class A {
  final static int a=9;
    static { //this block is not executing ??
      System.out.println("static block of A");
     }
}

class Manager {
  static {
    System.out.println("manager sib");
  }

  public static void main(String ...arg) {
    System.out.println("main");
    System.out.println(A.a);
  }
}
```

Why doesn't the static block of Class A run?

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code in your questoin. Currently it's unreadable.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that `A.a` is a [constant variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

> A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.

Therefore your `Manager.main` method is compiled *exactly* as if it were:

```
public static void main(String ...arg) {
    System.out.println("main");
    System.out.println(9);
}
```

There's no real reference to `A.a` any more, so the `A` class doesn't even need to *exist*, let alone be initialized. (You can delete `A.class` and still run `Manager`.)

If you're relying on using `A.a` to make sure the type is initialized, you shouldn't add a no-op method instead:

```
public static void ensureClassIsInitialized() {
}
```

then just call *that* from your `main` method. It's very unusual to need to do this though.

Comment: Thanks i was not doing it in my program but it was asked to me in an interview why static block of A will not run...

Comment: Yeah ,But if `Final` would have not been there with `int a=9` then static would have worked why its not executing with final...pls help me out!!

Comment: @Sandepp1: Without `final`, it wouldn't be a compile-time constant expression.

Answer (score 1):

Specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf
Section 4.12.1 Says,

A variable of primitive type or type String, that is final and initialized with a
   compile-time constant expression (§15.28), is called a constant variable.
   Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect
   to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility (§13.1, §13.4.9) and definite
   assignment (§16).

As you are only accessing the constant, class initialization is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can force-load whatever class you need:

```java
public final class ClassUtils {
  private ClassUtils() {}

  public static void forceLoad(Class<?>... classes) {
    for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
      try {
        Class.forName(clazz.getName(), true, clazz.getClassLoader());
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(clazz.getName(), e);
      }
    }
  }
}

class Manager {
  static {
    ClassUtils.forceLoad(A.class);
// ...
  }

  public static void main(String ...arg) {
// ...
  }
}
```