# Static block is never run

Tags: java, static

I have a utility class that looks like this:

```
public final class MyUtils {

     public static final List<String> MY_VALUES = new ArrayList<String>();

     {
         MY_VALUES.add("foo");
         MY_VALUES.add("bar");
     }
}
```

I call this from another class just like this:

```
MyUtils.MY_VALUES
```

If I do so, the list is empty and if I debug I see the static block is never run.

As I understand from the answers to [When does static class initialization happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization) and [How to force a class to be initialised?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560103/best-way-to-force-a-java-class-to-be-loaded) the block should run when `a static field of the class is assigned`, which I do right away. I also tried making the variable non-final to fulfill the condition "`a non-constant static field is used`".

I could use an init method as also sugested in the two other questions and als in [Why doesn't my static block of code execute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15509337/why-doesnt-my-static-block-of-code-execute) but I would still like to understand why it isn't working in the first place although I seem to have fulfilled the conditions from the language specification.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add the `static` keyword in front of your block in order to make it static:

```
public final class MyUtils {

     public static final List<String> MY_VALUES = new ArrayList<String>();

     static {
         MY_VALUES.add("foo");
         MY_VALUES.add("bar");
     }
}
```

A **initialization block** gets called everytime the class is constructed.

A **static initialization block** gets called only once at the start of your program.

Comment: That works, thanks. Will be a few minutes until I can accept your answer. Could you explain what the difference to the construct without the `static` keyword is? I used that before and it always worked so far (e.g. if I call static methods, the block was run before).

Comment: Not exactly correct. Initialization block gets called every time **object** of the class is constructed. A static initialization block gets called first time the class is used (more or less).